# Translating a taxonomy term does not populate content into fields

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

When translating a node into another language it does the following:

- automatically populates all fields with content from the source node on the edit form
- ensures the two nodes are linked as translations
- defaults to the second language (if only two enabled)

When you press 'translate' on a taxonomy term it loads a blank form (as if you are creating a new term).

How do I duplicate the behaviour of the node 'translate' link for taxonomy term 'translate' - to create the same one-click functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one compromise solution that needs Replicate & Replicate UI modules:

1. Go to relevant taxonomy term and click 'replicate'
2. Edit replicated taxonomy term as necessary and switch language
3. Create a new 'translation set' to link the two taxonomy terms as
   translations of each other

This solution isn't suitable for my end-users because of the third step. The 'translate' feature for nodes automatically links the two pieces of content as translations.